# In graphQL, If I send too many query sometimes graphql occurs Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400 how can I solve it?

Tags: javascript, mysql, typescript, graphql, apollo-server

In graphQL, If I send too many query sometimes graphQL occurs Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400 how can I solve it?
Queries almost activate well, but sometimes there are too many queries like too many click query button. Then that error occur. If there are any way to solve it?
I'm using graphQL, apollo

Comment: You need to add more information. What is the exact response body? what do your logs say?

Comment: just query. There are not special things.  Get some data from server. It works well. But sometimes that error occur. I think too many query cause server does not understand client's request.

Comment: Sometimes when your server is too busy, it can fail. To understand why and how to fix this, it is just not enough to say 'sometimes error occur', Details are important. If you don't provide them, nobody will be able to help you.